# iOS Parse Push Notification Push sent 0 from Parse Website

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, devicetoken

I am unable to receive push notifications from parse website, it says sent to 2 devices but pushes sent is coming out to be 0, I can see my devices with id and all, in the installation class of parse core.

I even used

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
...
}
```

in order to display any error but nothing was found.
Any suggestion on how to tackle this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are not using a valid push notification certificate. If you log in to your iOS developer account and click on your App ID it should say "enabled" with a green dot next to push notifications for development or distribution, whatever you're working with. If it does not you need to generate a push notification certificate for your app using the "+" button at the top of the page.